# ERROR Command failed: gradlew.bat assembleRelease --stacktrace

Tags: java, android, web-applications, trusted-web-activity, bubblewrap

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- What went wrong:
  unable to create native thread: possibly out of memory or process/resource limits reached

bubblewrap build for Building the Android App

Try:
Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

Exception is:
java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: unable to create native thread: possibly out of memory or process/resource limits reached
at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ManagedExecutorImpl.execute(ManagedExecutorImpl.java:39)

Comment: Is this reproducible? If so, what URL are you using, and what's the exact Bubblewrap command line you're using?